# How to pass variable on button click in Inline Keyboard in Telegraf?

Tags: node.js, telegram, chatbot, telegraf

I found this solution that helps to solve my problem:

```
function makeMenu(clientId){
  let clientButton = [Markup.callbackButton(' '+clientId+' Information', 'info-'+clientId)]
  return Markup.inlineKeyboard([clientButton])
}

bot.action(/^[client]+(-[a-z]+)?$/, ctx => {
  console.log(ctx.match[1].split('-')[1] )
})
```

But this is a poor solution or a workaround because I need to pass a long list of parameters and there is a limitation in the telegram's api to pass strings up to 64 bytes.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution to the issue you're facing would be to put the large data inside a database and passing an Id (or a ref to that data) as the callback data and using the code you've posted.
An example code would be:

```
function makeMenu(clientId){
  const id = storeDataToDB('info-'+clientId) // store the large data to DB in here
  let clientButton = [Markup.callbackButton(' '+clientId+' Information', id)]
  return Markup.inlineKeyboard([clientButton])
}
bot.action(/^[client]+(-[a-z]+)?$/, ctx => {
  const data = getDataFromDB(ctx.match[1].split('-')[1]) // fetch the data from DB and continue..
  console.log(data)
})
```

You could use firebase, mongodb, or any other DB.. (just make sure the ID adheres to the limit imposed by telegram)